# Python (googletrans) - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, googletrans

Trying to detect language code in Python using **googletrans**. But it generating ERROR (Refer error block for info).

**Require solution for the same**

Code :

```
import googletrans
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
result = translator.translate('Mitä sinä teet')
print(result.src)
print(result.dest)
print(result.origin)
print(result.text)
print(result.pronunciation)
```

Error:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py in _update(self)
     60 
     61         # this will be the same as python code after stripping out a reserved word 'var'
---> 62         code = self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1).replace('var ', '')
     63         # unescape special ascii characters such like a \x3d(=)
     64         code = code.encode().decode('unicode-escape')

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: @Steve always good to check the GitHub issues page first, this exact error ended up being there, along with a workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known, reported issue in the `googletrans` library's github page. Take a look there to see the status of the fix and potential work arounds: https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues.

According to the most recent comment, installing a different version, `googletrans==4.0.0-rc1`, appears to work, but with caveats:

> ***fire17** commented 16 days ago*
> normal pip installation failed but uninstalled and reinstalled
> googletrans==4.0.0-rc1
> then worked :)
> tho the object is wierd, i can access the translated text like
>
> ```
> a = translator.translate("hi")
> translated_text = a.__dict__()["text"]
> ```

Comment: it is [AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' · Issue #354 · ssut/py-googletrans · GitHub](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/354)

`a = translator.translate("Guten Abend")` then `a.text` gives `'Good evening'` :-)

Answer (score 5):

It worked post re-installing googletrans

*pip install googletrans==4.0.0-rc1*

Comment: This works for me, nice and simple solution!