# I can't understand why googletrans in python isn't working, it gives error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-translate

I was just trying to understand how to use googletrans in python and I wrote out the following code:

```
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator() 

result = translator.translate('Mikä on nimesi', src='fi', dest='fr')

print(result.src)
 
print(result.dest)
 
print(result.text)
```

But for some reason it gives me the error message:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

I have installed google translate with pip install googletrans, and was trying to follow the instructions on this site: https://py-googletrans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ but for some reason it doesn't work. I'm running on kali linux operating system. Could someone please explain to me how to fix the issue?

Ps: here's a screenshot of the message:

[image]

Comment: Looks like an internal error. I'd say `googletrans` is broken.

Comment: Known issue, look at their GitHub next time please: https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/299

Comment: @RandomDavis it doesn't write a solution to it there is there any way to solve the issue? Or is there some other translation module I can use in python?

Comment: @MichaelBlane all I know about the issue is what I read from that thread, so I have no idea if there's a way to solve the issue. Probably not, as it's likely being caused by the Google Translate API returning data in a different format than the library expects, as it's an unofficial library. Also StackOverflow does not really allow questions that are purely asking for a library or software recommendation. I don't know of any Python translation libraries, I think you'll have to do your own research on that. Or wait for googletrans to be fixed.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65957959/python-googletrans-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googletrans is currently broken. From the [docs](https://py-googletrans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can be seen that de build is failing. Seeing a `D` for maintainability doesn't look good, but I'm not familiar with this benchmark.

[image]

You could try an older version that is passing the build, or fix the issue because it's open-source.

Answer (score 1):

Use googletrans version 3.1.0a0 or above.